# Emptying jugs by choosing partition of subsets with fixed constant

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, and $c\in[0,1/2]$ a fixed constant independent of $n$. We have $2^n-1$ jugs of water labeled with distinct nonempty subsets of $A=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. A jug labeled with a subset of size $k$ contains $c^k(1-c)^{n-k}$ liters of water. An allowed operation is to choose some jugs whose labels form a partition of $A$, and pour out the same amount of water from each of these jugs. Does there exist $c$ such that for all $n$, we can empty the water in all jugs using this operation repeatedly?

For example, when $n=4$ we can empty all jugs as follows (for any $c\in[0,1/2]$):

- Pour out all water from the jug labeled $\{1,2,3,4\}$.
- Pour out $c^3(1-c)$ liters of water from the jugs labeled $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{4\}$. (Note that $c^3(1-c)\le c(1-c)^3$, so we can do this.) Similarly with $\{1,2,4\}$ and $\{3\}$, $\{1,3,4\}$ and $\{2\}$, and $\{2,3,4\}$ and $\{1\}$.
- Pour out $c(1-c)^3-c^3(1-c)=c(1-c)(1-2c)$ liters of water from the jugs labeled $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\}$.
- Pour out $c^2(1-c)^2$ liters of water from the jugs labeled $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$. Similarly with $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2,4\}$, and $\{1,4\}$ and $\{2,3\}$.

In general, we can empty a jug whose label has size at least $n/2$ by pairing it with its complement, but how can we make sure we empty the jugs with label of size less than $n/2$? For small enough $c$ (in terms of $n$) this can be done by using the singletons to empty everything else. If we were to allow $c$ to be as high as close to $1/2$, [this question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596374/emptying-jugs-by-choosing-partition-of-subsets) shows that the task is not possible.

Comment: I wonder where do the numbers $c^k(1-c)^{n-k}$ come from . Is this question motivated by something else ?? All I noticed is that because of the binomial theorem all the jugs contain $1-(1-c)^n$ water in total . I also thought this may be related to probability : it's the probability that a biased coin with probability $c$ of heads will reveal exactly $k$ heads after $n$ throws .